# how do i get mysql warning messages in php (not error)

Tags: php, mysql, message, warnings

i want to execute a sql at php which does something like changing a text column into int column.

however, this sql failed to fun at php and succeeds in my mysql admin tool (sqlyog). server responses "1 row(s) affected. 1 warning(s)". but "SHOW WARNINGS" didn't pop up anything and not surprisingly, php's mysql_error() didn't return anything.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best is to use the mysqli extension instead of the old mysql extension, as mysqli supports all of MySQL's features and offers the [mysqli_get_Warnings()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.get-warnings.php) function. Without mysqli you can do `mysql_query("SHOW WARNINGS");` (see [SHOW WARNINGS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-warnings.html) docs) and then read the warnings from the result set.